# Defining a constant as a coefficient from an r regression

Tags: r, regression, constants, coefficients

I am trying define a constant as a coefficient from an r regression. I.e. trying to define elasticity as the number -1.64431 that you can see in the photo.

[image]

```
reg <- lm(ln_q ~ ln_price, data=df) 
elasticity <- reg[["coefficients","ln_price"]]
print(elasticity)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in reg[["coefficients", "ln_price"]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: I'm guessing you might want - `coef(reg)["ln_price"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elasticity <- reg$coefficients[names(reg$coefficients)=="ln_price"]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that others will understand. Only posting a code won't work.